# Active class in CSS

Tags: html, css

For some reason the active class doesn't have any effect on my page. Would be very grateful for someone to take a peek and explain why it doesn't.

```css
.nav-item {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover,
.active {
  color: #f3ef36;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#">Hem</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="meny.html">Meny</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

From the examples I've checked on w3schools and others it should work fine, but for some reason the active class doesn't seem to bite in this context. The hover pseudoclass works but not the active class I've manually typed in the different list elements.

Comment: So, are you referring to the :active pseudo-element for an <a> tag? Because it looks like you have a CSS definition for a class named 'active'. Try putting an 'a' in front of the period in active: **a.active**

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read on [CSS specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Rules on selector `.nav-item a` will always have precedence over `.active`.

You need to increase the specificity e.g. like this `a.active`

See the snippet below:

```css
header {background:#000}

.nav-item {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover,
a.active {
  color: #f3ef36;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#">Hem</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="meny.html">Meny</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-item {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.nav-item a {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-item a:hover,
.active {
  color: #f3ef36;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="active" href="#">Hem</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="meny.html">Meny</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!